# ASP.NET MVC3 RC2 Does not update the model 2nd time

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

I am trying to update model from the FormCollection for two distinct collections of model. IT only works for the first time. Here is the sample code:

```
        public ActionResult Edit(int id, FormCollection form)
    {
        Order ord = pr.GetOrder(id);
        TryUpdateModel<Order>(ord, form.ToValueProvider());

        IEnumerable<OrderItem> items = new List<OrderItem>();
        IEnumerable<OrderPayment> pmts = new List<OrderPayment>();
        /* 1. */ TryUpdateModel<IEnumerable<OrderItem>>(items, "oitm", form.ToValueProvider());
        /* 2. */ TryUpdateModel<IEnumerable<OrderPayment>>(pmts, "opmt", form.ToValueProvider());
        //Save the model 
        return PartialView("IndexItem", inv);
    }
```

It populates the model for Order and items, but does not update pmts collection from formcollection. I checked the form collection and it does have all the properties for the opmt prefix. If I switch the TryUpdateModel between 1 and 2 then it updates the pmts successfully and not the items. 
My assumptions are as follows:

1. It may be something to do with multiple TryUpdateModel on a collection.
2. Once I get the ModelState Error then it will not update following try to update model

What am I doing wrong here???

THIS SAME CODE and MODELS were WORKING FOR MVC2!

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

GREAT!

RTM release of MVC3 has fixed this issue. So looks like it was bug but no one acknowledged it. Anyways its fixed.

Great release, Thanks to MVC team.